# Compilation of XSLT is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, uwp

### Problem

I'm making a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app. I'm trying to convert `.xml` and `.xsl` into `.html` file to make a pdf file finally, but `XslCompiledTransform` throws an error when loading `.xsl` file on Visual Studio 2022. I have no idea about on which platform XSLT compilation isn't supported neither which platform I'm now on. I couldn't find relevent information on Google. Any help is greatly appreciated.

### Source code

MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
        private async void ConvertXML2HTML(IStorageFile xmlFile, IStorageFile xslFile)
        {
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream xslStream = await xslFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            System.IO.Stream xslStreamNet = xslStream.AsStream();
            XmlReader xmlReaderXsl = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(xslStreamNet);
            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslt.Load(xmlReaderXsl, settings, null);  // This line throws
            // System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Compilation of XSLT is not supported on this platform.'
        }
```

Package.appxmanifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
  ...
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  ...
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

xsl file used in the code above.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
                <title>document title</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                ...

                </style>
            </head>
            <body style="word-break:break-all;">
                <table border="0" width="100%" style="center" >
                        <td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;">
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </td>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SomeString">
        <xsl:if test="count(Text)!=0">
            <xsl:call-template name="loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="end_1" select="count(Text)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="count_1" select="1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    ...
    <xsl:template name="zero-padding">
        <xsl:param name="str"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$str!=''"><xsl:value-of select="number($str)"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$str=''">0</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="zero-padding2">
        <xsl:param name="str"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$str!=''"><xsl:value-of select="number($str)"/>．</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$str=''">0．</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### What I tried

Though I knew it is not a JScript error, I tried the code below. It didn't work.

```cs
            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            var settings = new XsltSettings();
            settings.EnableScript = true;

            xslt.Load(xmlReaderXsl, settings, null);
```

Comment: if it says that xslt compilation is not supported, maybe just use `XslTransform` instead of `XslCompiledTransform`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, UWP requires you to read/write via `Windows.Storage` namespace, which `XslTransform` doesn't support. I'm happy to say good bye to UWP if it solves a problem while supporting recent versions.

Comment: The documentation of XslCompiledTransform at e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=net-7.0 doesn't list UWP (in the "Applies to " section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=net-7.0#applies-to) while for e.g. XmlWriter at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=net-7.0 it does explicitly have it listed: "UWP 10.0". I don't know what Microsoft advertises as the UWP successor, MAUI or WinUI or something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right. I'll thin the next step I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the class **XsltProcessor** in the **Windows.Data.Xml.Xsl** namespace. Pass a reference to your XSLT file in the constructor. After that call the method **TransformToDocument** and pass the method a reference to the XML file you want to transform.